# how to Asynchronously consume from 2 RabbitMQ queues from one consumer using pika

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I am writing a Consumer that need to consume from two different queues.

1-> for the actual messages(queue declared before hand).

2-> for command messages to control the behavior of the consumer(dynamically declared by the consumer and binds to an existing exchange with a routing key in a specific format(need one for each instance of consumer running))

I am using selection connection to consume async'ly.

```
    self.channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count = self.prefetch_count)
    log.info("Establishing channel with the Queue: "+self.commandQueue)
    print "declaring command queue"
    self.channel.queue_declare(queue=self.commandQueue,
                                durable = True,
                                exclusive=False,
                                auto_delete=True,
                                callback = self.on_command_queue_declared)
```

The queue is not being declared or the callback is not getting called.

On the other hand the messages from the actual message Queue are not being consumed since i added this block of code.

Pika logs do not show any errors nor the consumer app crashes.

does anybody know why this is happening or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I even tried to use a queue that is allready existing for the command queue. and did a basic_consume on both the queues but neither of the queues are being consumed.

Comment: Do you need to consume messages from the different queues to separate functions, or can messages from the different queue call the same function?

Comment: It would be ideal to consume in a different callback method. but it you could get it to consume to the same method that will be great too.

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at the example here: http://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/asynchronous_consumer_example.html ?

And some blocking examples:
http://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/blocking_consume.html
http://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/blocking_consumer_generator.html

Blocking and Select connection comparison: http://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/comparing_publishing_sync_async.html

Blocking and Select connections in pika 0.10.0 pre-release are faster and there are a number of bug fixes in that version.

Comment: Yes, I did. My consumer looks very similar to the sync consumer example. It works fine when consuming from a single queue. But the problem is my consumer needs to consume from multiple queues. Is there an example for that?

Comment: correction: My consumer looks very similar to the async consumer example

Comment: Please post a complete code sample that demonstrates your issue. It will make it easier for the community to help you.